# Pygame exit code 139

Tags: pygame, pixel, exit-code

```
PIXAR = pygame.PixelArray(SCREEN)  
PIXAR[110][0] = WHITE
```

When I add this to my code, I get:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

followed by a OS message that python quit unexpectedly. If I remove it:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can't seem to find a solution; the 1.9.2 manual does not explain this. If I'm missing it in the reading, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think `PIXAR` is a two dimensional array. It should be accessed with `PIXAR[110,0]` instead of `PIXAR[110][0]`.